# Python lxml use iterparse to only get top level occurrences of Elements

Tags: python-3.x, xml, lxml

I have the following MWE where I want to archieve to have a list with all top-level rdf:Description Elememts in entries. The actual Dump I’m trying to parse has over 2 Million of those Elememts, that’s why I specifically want to use `iterparse`:

```py
from io import BytesIO
from lxml import etree
from copy import deepcopy
xmlstring = """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"  xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"  xmlns:wdrs="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/powder-s#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
<rdf:Description rdf:about="https://ld.zdb-services.de/resource/5-X">
    <dc:subject rdf:datatype="https://d-nb.info/standards/elementset/dnb#ddc-subject-category">940</dc:subject>
    <wdrs:describedby>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="https://ld.zdb-services.de/data/5-X">
            <dcterms:license rdf:resource="http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/"/>
            <dcterms:modified rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2020-03-18T12:21:08.000</dcterms:modified>
        </rdf:Description>
    </wdrs:describedby>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="https://ld.zdb-services.de/resource/7-3">
    <dc:subject rdf:datatype="https://d-nb.info/standards/elementset/dnb#ddc-subject-category">590</dc:subject>
    <wdrs:describedby>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="https://ld.zdb-services.de/data/7-3">
            <dcterms:license rdf:resource="http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/"/>
            <dcterms:modified rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2021-11-03T21:41:02.000</dcterms:modified>
        </rdf:Description>
    </wdrs:describedby>
    <dcterms:issued rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">1963-2008</dcterms:issued>
    <owl:sameAs>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="https://d-nb.info/01000002X">
            <owl:sameAs>
                <rdf:Description rdf:about="https://ld.zdb-services.de/resource/7-3">
                    <owl:sameAs rdf:resource="http://hub.culturegraph.org/resource/DNB-01000002X"/>
                </rdf:Description>
            </owl:sameAs>
        </rdf:Description>
    </owl:sameAs>
</rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
"""
entries = []
for event, elem in etree.iterparse(BytesIO(xmlstring.encode("UTF-8")), tag='{http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#}Description' ,events=("start", "end")):
    if elem.tag == "{http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#}Description" and event == "end":
        entries.append(elem)
    elem.clear()
len(entries)
```

This code now returns 6 because it find six starting `<rdf:Description` tags. I want to extract each Element like I would if I would use `parse` and `tree.findall('./rdf:Description', NAMESPACES)`. Thanks for your help!

---

Edit:

I since found out that filtering for the parent tag helps selecting:

```py
entries = []
for event, elem in etree.iterparse(BytesIO(xmlstring.encode("UTF-8")), events=("start", "end")):
    if elem.tag == "{http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#}Description" and event == "end":
        if elem.getparent().tag == "{http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#}RDF":
            entries.append(deepcopy(elem))
        elem.clear()
```

But the deepcopy of the element is still missing the nested description tags. So this works_

```py
for e in entries:
    print(e.attrib['{http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#}about'])
```

but this doesn’t:

```py
for e in entries:
    print(e.find('.//{http://purl.org/dc/terms/}:modified').text)
```

because somehow the inner `<rdf:Description>` Tag is lost.

Comment: So you want just the `rdf:Description` elements that are immediate children of the `rdf:RDF` root element. Is that right?

Comment: yes thats right. Them and all children.

Comment: I am confused about what you really want, There is no deepcopying being done in the MWE code. You wrote: "This code now returns 6 because...". That is apparently wrong, What do you want the code to return?

Comment: If you run the first example it returns 6 elements. After that I encountered that by using `if elem.getparent().tag == "{http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#}RDF":` I could filter the output and by using `deepcopy` I would actually create a usable copy of the element. I do want the list `entries` to be populated by the complete tree below the `<rdf:Description>` Elements that are immediate children of the rdf:RDF root element.

Comment: Elements are lost because of `elem.clear()` as far as I can tell.

Comment: This is really confusing. What do you want to do with the elements afterwards? You could just use a list comprehension or if a list with 2 million entries is too 'slow' write a generator function.

Answer (score 0):

Why not choose a generator expression or list comprehension?

```
elements = (elem.attrib['{http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#}about'] for event, elem in etree.iterparse(BytesIO(xmlstring.encode("UTF-8")), tag='{http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#}Description' ,events=("start", "end")) if elem.tag == "{http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#}Description" and event == "end")
```

This yields six entries. Is this what you want to achieve?

```
In [11]: next(gen)
Out[11]: 'https://ld.zdb-services.de/data/5-X'
```